# Comparing v8 strings (Node.js addon)

Tags: c++, v8

I have this:

```
  if (!args[2]->IsString() || (*args[2]->ToString() != "true" && *args[2]->ToString() != "false")) {
        Nan::ThrowTypeError("Third argument to 'replace-line' must be a string representing whether to find or replace.");
        return;
    }
```

but I get a compilation errors andwarnings:

```
../hello.cpp:49:58: error: comparison between distinct pointer types ‘v8::String*’ and ‘const char*’ lacks a cast [-fpermissive]
../hello.cpp:49:92: warning: comparison with string literal results in unspecified behaviour [-Waddress]
     if (!args[2]->IsString() || (*args[2]->ToString() != "true" && *args[2]->ToString() != "false")) {
```

how can I properly compare v8 strings with plain C strings?

Answer (score 0):

You can convert using `v8::String::NewFromOneByte` detailed [in the documentation](http://bespin.cz/~ondras/html/classv8_1_1String.html#afa8026ed1337564a9fd15dc56aceaa83) there are also other sources if you want.

If you want to go the other way it looks like you would have to create your own buffer and use `WriteOneByte`.

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a [v8::String::Utf8Value](https://v8docs.nodesource.com/io.js-3.0/d4/d1b/classv8_1_1_string_1_1_utf8_value.html) like `v8::String::Utf8Value arg(args[2]->ToString())` and compare that to C string literals (event though use `strcmp/strncmp` instead of `==` or construct an `std::string` from it).

Answer (score 0):

## *V8* is for Javascript

How do you *properly* compare two strings in Javascript?

```
"String 1" === "String 2"
```

How do you *properly* compare two values in Javascript?

```
value1 === value2
```

---

## The magic of `===` is also available in C++

Do not extract the internal character values for comparing.
**Compare (`===`) the `v8::Value`s.**

Assuming `args[2]` is a `v8::Local<v8::Value>` and not an empty handle, you may do:

```
Isolate *isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
v8::Local<v8::String> h_true = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "true");
v8::Local<v8::String> h_false = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "false");
if(args[2]->StrictEquals(h_true) || args[2]->StrictEquals(h_false) == false)
{
    v8::Local<v8::String> h_error_message = v8::String::NewFromUtf8(
        isolate,
        "The argument must be a \"true\" or a \"false\"."
    );
    v8::Local<v8::Error> h_error = v8::Exception::RangeError(h_error_message);
    isolate->ThrowException(h_error);
    return;
}
```

However, since you're using *Nan*, things can be much simpler:

```
if(info[2]->StrictEquals(Nan::New("true")) // arguments[2] === "true"
|| info[2]->StrictEquals(Nan::New("false")) // arguments[2] === "false"
== false)
{
    Nan::ThrowRangeError("The argument must be a \"true\" or a \"false\".");
    return;
}
```

**You don't even have to check if the argument is a string, nor if it is provided by the caller.**